# Removing background colour from ls command result in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, background-color, ls

I am a beginnner to Ubuntu. By somehow without my knowledge, I changed the background colour of `ls` command result to green which is really annoying and I do not know how to set it back to black. I tried adding the below entry in `.bashrc` script but in vain.

```
export LS_COLORS="ow=30"
```

So can someone tell me how to change the background color to black?

[image: Screen shot of my terminal]

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is the `dircolors` utility which outputs a sequence of shell commands to set up the terminal for color output from `ls`. Place the following command at the end of your .bashrc:

```
eval "`dircolors`"
```

For explanation enter `info dircolors` to the terminal or visit the site containing the manual [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/dircolors-invocation.html).

Comment: actually when i changed the file permission of that directory using chmod 744 $directory , the bg green color went off..But i now face a problem of not able to change colors/attributes of ls command listings which is explained in the following question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21030102/changing-color-of-my-directories-listed-by-my-directory.. kindly answer it

Comment: @aarish Looks like it has already been answered. I agree with that answer.